# loglog regression with 0's in IV's

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, logarithm, feature-scaling

Assume we have 2 predictors $X_1$ and $X_2$ and an outcome $Y$ that we wish to model with the following function

$y = e^{\beta_0} * X_1 ^{\beta_1} * X_2^{\beta_2}$

Also assume that we have some priors for our parameters $\beta_0,\beta_1, \beta_2$ and we run MCMC as to generate posterior samples of our parameter estimates thus we do not need to linearize the equation as is normally done in loglog regression.

The values for $X_1, X_2$ is in general in the interval $[0,100]$.

My question is now; how should i deal with zeros in $X_1, X_2$ and maybe $Y$.

My idea is to add $1$ to solely the zero entries in $X_1, X_2$ but i assume this also creates some sort of bias. Is it better to add a small positive float instead like $0.01$ or maybe even getting rid of the predictor entirely thus having some sort of indicator variable including the term or not when having zeros?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you have to do anything? You’re not taking the logarithm of these zero-values.

Comment: Adding small numbers first before taking logarithms isn't conservative and can easily create moderate or strong outliers out of those zeros with considerable leverage. I use regression-type jargon but I guess similar problems could arise with your fitting method.

Comment: @Dave since there might still be an effect from the other variables and having one of them as 0 disregards this, one could obviously then start to point to other models since this behavior is not wanted. Shouldnt my indicator variable approach however solve for this?